# PHP - how do I write code to login to a web site?

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I would like to write a PHP script that will go to a website, enter my userid and password, and retrieve data.  What PHP functions or classes can I get that will do that?

I have already tried PHP file_get_contents, which works great except it does not submit userids and passwords.  Then I started looking at cURL, but was not sure if that is the best way to go.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** My mistake, check out [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

[Use cURL to login to websites](http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/use-curl-login-websites-script)

[cURL Tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)

[Getting started with cURL](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/working-with-curl-getting-started-the-easy-way-on-win32/)

There are several articles [on this subject](http://www.knowledgesutra.com/forums/topic/38162-automatic-login-using-curl/)

Comment: That is not related to my question, I am not asking how to have others login to my site.  I am asking how to write a script that IT will login to anothers site.  A web spidering program, a bot, a google crawler etc.

Comment: +1 however there's no answer on the forum topic that you linked to.

Comment: sorry, check edits.  I thought the OP was asking a different question originally.

Comment: I'm referring to the "cURL auto login" link to webdeveloper.com. There's a question but no answer over there.

Comment: Got it, I copied the wrong link.